# Fredholm equation

Tags: calculus

Let $f,g:[0,1]\to \Bbb{R}$ be continuous functions.

We have that

$$\int_0^1 k(x,y)f(y)dy=g(x)$$ and $$\int_0^1 k(x,y)g(y)dy=f(x)$$ with $k:[0,1]\times[0,1] \to \Bbb{R}_{>0}$ continuous. I hope to prove $f=g$.